# Firebase & angular2: Can I create request for filter by value

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Can I create request to table 'User' for filter by value one field, I don't want get all record in table 'user'.
For example: I have array.

```
[{email: "email1@ar.rom", password: "111"}, {email: "email2@ar.rom", password: "111"}]
```

I created request:

```
af: AngularFire;

this.af.database.object('/users/',{
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'password',
            equalTo: '14714711'
        }
    })
```

This request get my 2 record. if want get 1 record. What my create request with filter by value 1 field?

Answer (score 2):

To limit to a single result, add `limitToFirst: 1` to your query:

```
this.af.database.object('/users/',{
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'password',
        equalTo: '14714711',
        limitToFirst: 1
    }
})
```

Since you're executing a query, you'll still get a list as a result. When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.